# My buttons in my kotlin app arent clickable. They arent responding

Tags: android, kotlin

> Here is my MainActivity.Kt file

```
package com.example.calculator

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.Expression
import java.text.DecimalFormat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button_clear.setOnClickListener {
            input.text = ""
            output.text = ""
        }
        button_bracket_left.setOnClickListener {
            input.text = addToInputText("(")
        }
        button_bracket_right.setOnClickListener {
            input.text  = addToInputText(")")
        }
        button_7.setOnClickListener {
            input.text  = addToInputText("7")
        }
        button_8.setOnClickListener {
            input.text  = addToInputText("8")
        }
        button_9.setOnClickListener {
            input.text  = addToInputText("9")
        }
        button_division.setOnClickListener {
            input.text  = addToInputText("÷")
        }
        button_4.setOnClickListener {
            input.text  = addToInputText("4")
        }
        button_5.setOnClickListener {
            input.text  = addToInputText("5")
        }
        button_6.setOnClickListener {
            input.text  = addToInputText("6")
        }
        button_multiplication.setOnClickListener {
            input.text  = addToInputText("×")
        }
        button_1.setOnClickListener {
            input.text  = addToInputText("1")
        }
        button_2.setOnClickListener {
            input.text  = addToInputText("2")
        }
        button_3.setOnClickListener {
            input.text  = addToInputText("3")
        }
        button_subtraction.setOnClickListener {
            input.text  = addToInputText("-")
        }
        button_addition.setOnClickListener {
            input.text = addToInputText("+")
        }
        button_0.setOnClickListener {
            input.text  = addToInputText("0")
        }
        button_dot.setOnClickListener {
            input.text  = addToInputText(".")
        }
        button_equals.setOnClickListener {
            input.text  = addToInputText("=")
        }
    }
    private fun addToInputText(buttonValue: String):String{
        return "${ input.text }$buttonValue"
    }
    private fun getInputExpression(): String{
        var expression =  input.text.replace(Regex("÷"), "/")
        expression = expression.replace(Regex("×"), "*")
        return expression
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun showResult(){
        try {
            val expression = getInputExpression()
            val result = Expression(expression).calculate()
            if (result.isNaN()){
                output.text = "Error"
                output.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red))

            }else {
                output.text = DecimalFormat("0.######").format(result).toString()
                output.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green))
            }


        }catch (e: Exception){
            output.text = "Error"
            output.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red))
        }

    }
}
```

> and here is my activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/window_background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/io_background"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            tools:text="5+10-3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/output"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            tools:text="12" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_clear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/c"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_bracket_left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/bracket_left"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_bracket_right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/bracket_right"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_division"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/division"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/_7"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/_8"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/_9"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_multiplication"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/multiplication"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/_4"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/_5"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/_6"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_subtraction"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/subtraction"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/_1"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/_2"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/_3"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_addition"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/addition"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/_0"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_dot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/dot"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_equals"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="@string/equals"/>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I am quite new to android programming and this is my first app i am working on in kotlin.
According to me i think everything has been coded properly, please help me out and see why my buttons cant seem to be clickable.I have read through it several times but cant seem to find where the problem is since i think i have used the setOnClickListener properly.

Comment: What do you mean by not clickable? Do they act like they're disabled and have no visual feedback that they are clicked? Have you tried setting a breakpoint in one of your click listeners and running in debug mode to see if the click listener is running its code when clicked?

Comment: Yes like they are disabled.When i click them its as if i am not clicking.

Answer (score 0):

*Issue is with your intialisation, You have used Synthetic, for intialisation, But that has not went fine*

**So Proceed using traditional one**

*On your kotlin class, declare variable*

```
lateinit var button_equals: AppCompatButton
```

*in your onCreate*

```
button_equals = findViewById(R.id.button_equals) as AppCompatButton
```

**All the best!!!, It works now**